# problem of setting cache as datatable and reading it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

and this is how i see if my cache is empty
all my syntax errors are coming when i am trying to see if the cache is null and if it is to run the stored procedure

```
 If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                If Cache["netcache"] = null Then
                    bcmd.CommandText = "yearlynetsales"
                Else
                    btable = cache["netcache"]
                end if
        If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                If Cache["salescache"] = null Then
                    bcmd.CommandText = "yearlysales"
                Else
                    btable = cache["salescache"]
                end if
    end if
```

this is how i set my cache

```
If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            Cache.Insert("netcache", bTable)
        ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            Cache.Insert("salescache", bTable)
        ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            Cache.Insert("cxsalescache", bTable)
        ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            Cache.Insert("cxvaluecache", bTable)
        ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
            Cache.Insert("othersalescache", bTable)
        ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
            Cache.Insert("inssalescache", bTable)
        End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like VB.NET. Use If Cache["netcache"] is nothing.
As far as know "= null" is C#. Not sure if it was introduced in VB.NET

Comment: is that the only thing wrong with it and how can i set the datatable to what is in the cache

Comment: Well thats the syntax error I could see. To update back to database you need to execute a stored procedure to update the data. I don see any code making a DB call in your question.